# Data Type for Images in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, sqldatatypes

I'm currently using the binary data type for images.

`$table->binary('image');`

An error gets raised when I try to save an image which is more than 64kb in size.

> #1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'pet_owner_id' at row
>   1.

In MySQL that data type is shown as `blob`.

Comment: Also read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: Typically, you'd store the image in the *filesystem* somewhere, and just the *path* in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datatype for image  `$table->binary('image'); //for blob`

**Storing binary data** Binary data, such as images, bloat your tables and cannot be displayed directly from a database, the following column types are designed for binary data:

- `TINYBLOB`: Up to 255 bytes
- `BLOB`: Up to 64KB
- `MEDIUMBLOB`: Up to 16MB
- `LONGBLOB`: Up to 4 GB

BLOB stands for **binary large object**